# Is it okay to use "create" as a property name in a JavaScript object literal?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jshint, ecmascript-5

I just noticed IDEA / JSHint telling me that an object literal which contains a property named "create" overrides a method in Object.

The literal is essentially:

```
module.exports = {email:{create:"me@me.com"}};
```

And (obviously?) Object has a create method defined in EcmaScript5.js

```
/**
@param {Object} proto
@param {Object} [props]
@static
@return {Object}
*/
Object.create = function(proto,props) {};
```

Is this something that could cause an obscure problem down the line?  I'm guessing that this reserved method doesn't apply to literals, or objects which haven't been instantiated with a default constructor. Just curious.

Comment: Reserved word in JS:
[link] http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Should not be a problem

Comment: seriously, downvote?  its just a simple question.

Comment: appreciated @Legends.  Thanks for not being a troll. =)

Comment: my guess is that since its not a reserved word, there's nothing wrong with intentionally or unintentionally overriding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing answers are correct but missing some important detail. What you are doing is absolutely fine and will not cause errors in any JavaScript environment.

The [`Object.create` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) that's been mentioned numerous times is *static*, which means is a property of the `Object` constructor itself, rather than its prototype. You are not overwriting it, or even shadowing it. It will still be accessible:

```
var obj = { create: 'something' };
console.log(obj.create); // 'something'
console.log(Object.create); // function create() { [native code] }
```

I'm not sure why JSHint or any other static analysis tool would warn against the use of `create` as a property identifier, except perhaps for the reason that it could cause some potential confusion.

Even your concern about `create` being a reserved word in JavaScript is a non-issue because modern JavaScript environments allow the use of reserved words as property identifiers, and `create` is not a reserved word in the first place:

```
var obj = {
  default: 1 // Reserved word as identifier
};
```

So in summary, you are safe to ignore the warning and don't worry about any potential side-effects your code might have had.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Thanks for your thoughtful response, James.

Answer (score 0):

It's [not reserved](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words.html), but it is *in use* (defined) on the `Object` object.

Since a literal object becomes an object too, the custom create() method would override the existing one.

Just use a different name for your method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not reserved, it's a valid identifier, but, as you said, you're overriding the Object create method on your literal. 
It will only affect if you try to use create on your literal.

```
myModule.email.create(); // Will fail
myModule.email.create; // "me@me.com"
```

Comment: so, if create is a function, and you do `email.create()` i guess the function will work, but you loose the ability to actually create an object from that object.

Comment: best answer.  thanks everybody for entertaining the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know when you create a global variable or method in JavaScript (in a browser) they become properties of the window object.

It is absolutely fine to introduce or even change the method definitions if you have a good reason to do so. Of course there are things that can go wrong if you change a method behavior. Here is an example - I overrode the window's open method.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
function windowOpen() {
window.open("http://www.google.com")
}

function windoOpenChange() {
window.open = function () {
alert("I won't open the window!");
};
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button value="open window" onClick="windowOpen()">Go to Google</button>
<button value="open window" onClick="windoOpenChange()">Change the behavior of window open</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is tested in FF. So the first click opens a new window and then when you click the second button the behavior of window.open is changed. Now when you click the first button again it will no longer open the new window. So yes this could be seen as an undesirable side effect if this is not what you intended to do.

The ability of being able to introduce new methods from other objects is called [Mixin](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/). And of course based on your mixin logic any mixin could run into conflicts not just built in objects.

The tools you are using are warning you against potential shadowing (unwanted override) of methods.